# FIle Services Resource Manager alternative for Windows Web Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, web-hosting, file-server

We need to provide disk quota managment for specific folders. On our hosting server Windows Web Server edition is installed. It has not File Server role that is why I cannot use FIle Services Resource Manager.

Is there any alternative product (it would be great if it is opensource or freeware) which can perform the same task?

Best regards,
Alexey Zakharov

Comment: why not just upgrade to standard? If it's a hosted server the cost can't be that much more and the feature requirement should certainly justify it

Comment: Jim B upgrade is money, also standard edition has other licence issues to be used as web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to the problem. In spite of the fact that Windows Web Server has no File Server Role it could install File Services Resource Manager as feature.

It is available in both Windows Web Server 2008 and Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

DO not use web server. MS' advice is that web server pulls the files over the network from a NAS location (like another server running windows standard). This is how I do it.

Comment: We have no licences to other windows server editions.